# Select all rows that has only specific value in records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains id, type.

I want to select all the ids that have only one or more records of the same type.

For example,

Assuming this is my table:

```
 id    type
456     4 
123     4 
123     4 
123    18 
123     4 
789     4 
789     4 
000     7
```

I want to get ids: 456,789 cause those ids have only records with type = 4:

456 has one record, and 789 has two records of type = 4.

123 has type = 4, but has type = 18.

How can I do it?

I know I can use partition, but I want something like join/exists..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/731e1

Comment: So you want to select all rows where there does `not exist` another row with the same id but a different type?   Hmmm, I wonder how you could do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT id
FROM cards
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(type) = MAX(type)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/731e1/2)

Comment: wow, I was thinking on a subquery with exists but this.. is far way better.

Comment: It doesn't work on sql server, but works on sqlFiddle:

SELECT id, type, status
FROM cards
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(type) = MAX(type) and type=4

Comment: Why do you add `type=4` in the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: @AlonShmiel Do you want to *select all the ids that have only one or more records of the same type* (as stated in the OP) **OR** *select all the ids that have only one or more records of the type=4*?

Comment: the second one.. Thank you!!

Comment: @AlonShmiel But this is not what you asked. That's a different question that has a different answer.

Comment: @AlonShmiel In this case try this instead: `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 4 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Id 
FROM cards
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [type]) = 1
```

Comment: I like this one, because it can easily be modified to find Ids that have just two, or maximum two types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @M.Ali answer mets your critera. His resultset includes id = '000'

```
if OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Work') is not null
    drop table #Work;
Create Table #Work (Id char(3), [Type] int)
insert into #Work values
 ( '456',  4) 
, ('123',  4) 
, ('123',  4) 
, ('123', 18) 
, ('123',  4) 
, ('789',  4) 
, ('789',  4) 
, ('000',  7)

select distinct * 
from #Work a 
where exists (
                select Type 
                    ,Count(Distinct Id) cntId
                from #Work b
                where a.Type = b.Type 
                group by Type
                having Count(Distinct Id) > 1
            )
and exists (
        select Id
            ,count(distinct Type)
        from #Work c
        where a.Id = c.Id
        group by id
        having count(distinct type)= 1
    )
```

output:

```
Id   Type
---- -----------
456  4
789  4
```